Подключение зашифрованной БД к проекту на winforms
Всем привет! Пишу приложение на winforms + sqlite. Необходимо было зашифровать БД, сделал это через sqlcipher и подключил новоиспеченную БД к проекту. Подключаю по паролю, файл видит, все хорошо, но выдаёт ошибку
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.118.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a9a2a02614f8a52" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."
Чтож, не беда, через менеджер пакетов NuGet подключаю System.Data.SQLite.SEE, но выходит, что это дело платное. Суть вопроса - как правильно в таком случае подключить зашифрованную бд? Или может другие способы найдутся
